# Getting error in ExampleInstrumentedTest.java file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, junit

My project run successfully expect that when I clean and rebuild the project I
getting this error

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]
D:\Gonna Projects\DoctorApps\app\src\androidTest\java\in\doctormobileapps\doctorapps\ExampleInstrumentedTest.java
Error:(4, 28) error: package android.support.test does not exist
Error:(5, 35) error: package android.support.test.runner does not exist
Error:(7, 17) error: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(8, 24) error: package org.junit.runner does not exist
Error:(11, 24) error: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(18, 2) error: cannot find symbol class RunWith
Error:(20, 6) error: incompatible types: Test cannot be converted to Annotation
Error:(23, 30) error: cannot find symbol variable InstrumentationRegistry
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 4.834 secs
Information:9 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

is there someone who can told me what's wrong i did?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you don't have added the Junit-Package to your *build.gradle* file for the module. Just add this in the *dependencies* block and it should work:

```
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: Then please provide the Code you are using for the Testclass and your build.gradle-file.

Comment: Fixed my issue! For some reason Android Studio didn't include the androidTestCompile line when it generated the build.gradle file...

Comment: `Configuration 'androidTestCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'androidTestImplementation' and 'androidTestApi'. It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html`

Answer (score 4):

When I create a new module from scratch, Android studio will produce a default gradle file with the following test related dependencies:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

This seems like it could solve at least some of the dependency issues in your build log. Since there is also a missing `org.junit` reference, possibly you also need to add junit as an `androidTestCompile` dependency, as @Chris already answered; or maybe it's implicitly included by espresso.

Answer (score 2):

There may be missing dependencies in your gradle build add these to line :

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
```

Answer (score 2):

i migrated to android x and i found the error below in my ExampleInstrumentedTest.java class.

[image: Error in ExampleInstrumentedTest.java]

i changed the code to

```
    Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
```

which solved my error problem.

Comment: This was the solution for me after migrated to android x